# retrieving data from json for windows phone 7

Tags: c#, json, web-services, windows-phone-7

I am planning to create a windows application(C#)that displays names of movies that are recently released.I have the url that displays data in json format.i want to retrieve only the movie name and the release date.From the Google searching i know i have to create a class but i do not know exactly how to start with..i am a new bee please guide me and also which version of Os is required i am currently using 7.1.below is the json from which i have to retrieve the data

```
{"total":47,"movies":[{"id":"771242005","title":"Magic Mike","year":2012,"mpaa_rating":"R","runtime":110,"critics_consensus":"Magic Mike's sensitive direction, smart screenplay, and strong performances allows audiences to have their beefcake and eat it too.","release_dates":{"theater":"2012-06-29","dvd":"2012-10-23"},"ratings":{"critics_rating":"Certified Fresh","critics_score":79,"audience_rating":"Upright","audience_score":63},"synopsis":"Set in the world of male strippers, Magic Mike is directed by Steven Soderbergh and stars Channing Tatum in a story inspired by his real life. The film follows Mike (Tatum) as he takes a young dancer called The Kid (Pettyfer) under his wing and schools him in the fine arts of partying, picking up women, and making easy money. -- (C) Warner Bros.","posters":{"thumbnail":"http://content8.flixster.com/movie/11/16/66/11166610_mob.jpg","profile":"http://content8.flixster.com/movie/11/16/66/11166610_pro.jpg","detailed":"http://content8.flixster.com/movie/11/16/66/11166610_det.jpg","original":"http://content8.flixster.com/movie/11/16/66/11166610_ori.jpg"},"abridged_cast":[{"name":"Channing Tatum","id":"162661835","characters":["Magic Mike"]},{"name":"Alex Pettyfer","id":"326298019","characters":["Adam","The Kid"]},{"name":"Matt Bomer","id":"771077752","characters":["Ken"]},{"name":"Joe Manganiello","id":"770800475","characters":["Big Dick Richie"]},{"name":"Matthew McConaughey","id":"162652350","characters":["Dallas"]}],"alternate_ids":{"imdb":"1915581"},"links":{"self":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771242005.json","alternate":"http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/magic_mike/","cast":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771242005/cast.json","clips":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771242005/clips.json","reviews":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771242005/reviews.json","similar":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771242005/similar.json"}}],"links":{"self":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/dvds/upcoming.json?page_limit=1&country=us&page=1","next":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/dvds/upcoming.json?page_limit=1&country=us&page=2","alternate":"http://www.rottentomatoes.com/dvd/upcoming.json"},"link_template":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/dvds/upcoming.json?page_limit={results-per-page}&page={page-number}&country={country-code}"}
```

Comment: Have you tried json2csharp? : http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: @PaulDiston - Thanks for posting that!

Answer (score 0):

You could try JSON.NET:  http://json.codeplex.com/

Note: I had to truncate the JSON string so the formatter here could handle it.

```
String JSONStr = @"{""total"":47,""movies"":[{""id"":""771242005"",""title"":""Magic....";

JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(JSONStr);

// movies is an array....of one.
Array Movies = jObject["movies"].ToArray();

foreach (JToken Movie in Movies)
    Response.Write(Movie["title"].ToString());
```

Comment: so is that all that i have write in mainPage.xaml.cs?

Comment: Well, something like that.  And add the JSON.NET dll to your project.

Comment: You may also want to add the JSON.NET reference via Nuget : http://nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json

Comment: thankq..what if i went to send the url and then FETCH the JSON dATA